# How to check if an extension is really used in Joomla

Tags: joomla

I want to know if a extension (for example: joomfish) is really used or not used at all before i disable it / uninstall it.

Is there a way to check ?

Answer (score 2):

First, in Joomla plugin has a specific meaning, so what you want to know is whether a component, module or plugin is used. 
This is a common problem when you inherit sites. A lot of times users install tons of extensions and never use or uninstall them.

The simplest first step with modules and plugins is to see if they are published or not. Also you can look at modules and see if they are assigned to any positions or menu items.

In terms of extensions, if they are a kind of extension that would be used to create content and you look at the manager you can see if any content was ever created. If not it is probably safe to uninstall. IF there is content then you will want to figure out whether you need o preserve it.

The problem with Mike's answer is .. how do you know if you have tried every possible combination of things or possible events with enough certainty to say for sure that something is not running ever. For example you may have a component that you never use as a menu item but then some module is running a query against its data.

Answer (score 0):

Well you cannot know that. To be absolutely shure you could write a system plugin which gets triggered on plugin calls and logs the triggering plugin names.